# Create Delegate in Typescript

Tags: ios, typescript, nativescript

I need to create a Delegate in my iOS App for use in my NSURLSession code. I know you can create one like this using javascript:

```
var MyAppDelegate = UIResponder.extend({

    // Implement a method from UIApplicationDelegate.
    // We will obtain the method signature from the protocol.
    applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions: function (application, launchOptions) {
        this._window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds);
        this._window.rootViewController = MyViewController.alloc().init();
        this._window.makeKeyAndVisible();
        return true;
    }
}, {
    // The name for the registered Objective-C class.
    name: "MyAppDelegate",
    // Declare that the native Objective-C class will implement the UIApplicationDelegate Objective-C protocol.
    protocols: [UIApplicationDelegate]
});
```

However, I am using Angular Nativescript so need it converted to Typescript. Any help?

So far, I have come up with the following:

```
class MyDelegate extends UIResponder implements UIApplicationDelegate {
    public static ObjCProtocols = [UIApplicationDelegate];
    applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions(application: UIApplication, launchOptions): boolean {
        return true;
    }
 }
 application.ios.delegate = MyDelegate;
```

It just won't allow me to add the:

```
this._window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds);
this._window.rootViewController = MyViewController.alloc().init();
this._window.makeKeyAndVisible();
```

part.

Comment: TypeScript IS JavaScript, and the code above will execute perfectly fine, what is the issue there?

Comment: As mentioned valid JavaScript is valid TypeScript. TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript. Is there a specific issue you are facing? Something that the TypeScript compilation is failing on?

Comment: It is more the intellisense showing there is an error. For example, cannot recognise there is a '.extend' on type UIResponder. As this bit of code will be going in a .ts file, shouldn't it all be written in Typescript?

Comment: Cast to <any> to instruct the TypeScript compiler that you know better.

`(<any>UIResponder).extend(...)`